# How to color a prompt on FreeBSD/cshrc?

Tags: freebsd, csh, tcsh

I'm being put in charge of managing a bunch of servers, I want to set up my prompts on each of them so that I don't get confused as to where I am logged in to.

I've edited my `.cshrc` files and put this in them:

```
set prompt=`whoami`@`hostname -s`:$cwd'$ '
```

But I'd like to color that prompt so it stands out a bit more. Maybe green with white text or something. How can I do that? I'm not very familiar with the shell syntax.

I'm SSH-ing in from the standard terminal that comes with Ubuntu, if that's relevant.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[This page](https://www.funtoo.org/Prompt_Magic) has a pretty good explanation, although the syntax is a bit different in `csh`. Here's what I came up with:

```
set prompt="%{\e[32;1m%}%n%{\e[37m%}@%{\e[33m%}%m%{\e[37m%}:%{\e[36m%}%~%{\e[37m%}"\$"%{\e[0m%} "
# root variation:
set prompt="%{\e[31;1m%}root%{\e[37m%}@%{\e[33m%}%m%{\e[37m%}:%{\e[36m%}%/%{\e[37m%}#%{\e[0m%} "
```

**update:** the previous prompt I had here didn't actually update when you changed directories. using `%n`, `%~` and `%m` instead of `$cwd` or `pwd` actually update. [see here](http://www.freebsdwiki.net/index.php/.cshrc).

`%{ ... %}` means the stuff between should take 0-width
`\e[ ... m` specifies the colors and bolding. `\e` escapes the `[` which seems to be necessary (I believe it's equivalent to `\033`), the `m` signifies the end.

Use `0` as your color to reset to default.

If you want to set a color and background, simply separate the numbers with semi-colons. Use `1` to enable bolding.

Consult this table to choose your colors:

[image]
<sub>(source: [funtoo.org](http://www.funtoo.org/images/1/1c/Colortable.gif))</sub>

So for example, "Hello World" in bold, cyan on a red background would be `%{\e[36;41;1m%}Hello World%{\e[0m%}`

Answer (score 4):

```
# Add these lines to your ~/.cshrc.mine file on the linux grace machines...

# Colors!
set     red="%{\033[1;31m%}"
set   green="%{\033[0;32m%}"
set  yellow="%{\033[1;33m%}"
set    blue="%{\033[1;34m%}"
set magenta="%{\033[1;35m%}"
set    cyan="%{\033[1;36m%}"
set   white="%{\033[0;37m%}"
set     end="%{\033[0m%}" # This is needed at the end... :(

# Setting the actual prompt

set prompt="${green}%n${blue}@%m ${white}%~ ${green}%%${end} "

# Clean up
unset red green yellow blue magenta cyan yellow white end
```

Comment: In tcsh (unlike bash), you can put whitespace before and after the '=', allowing you to vertically left-align both your variable names and values.

Answer (score 3):

To my knowledge FreeBSD comes with tcsh by default. Have a look at the [examples](http://www.tcsh.org/PromptExamples).

Another [list for other shells](http://www.understudy.net/custom.html) as well (bash, **csh**, tcsh, ksh, etc.) is available. Taken from that link and tested with tcsh (I do not have csh installed):

> To color the prompt you will want to place this symbol in your prompt. `%{\033[Xm%}`.
>
> Certain colors need a semicolon in order to appear. Yellow […] is 1;33 do not use just 33 or it will come out brown. If you have a 0;31 you don't need to place the 0.

The colours are ANSI. Have a look at the [ANSI colours list](http://www.understudy.net/custom.html#table2); simply replace `X` with the colour code.

X = 0 resets the colours: `%{\033[0m%}`.

Comment: Well, the `.cshrc` file existed, and editing that changed my prompt. Does `tcsh` use the same file? How can I find out which one is running?

Comment: @Mark: Yes, it uses the same file. My one has a `if ($?tcsh) then` block for tcsh-specifics. Check using `env | grep -i shell`.

Comment: I didn't say that. They're just not very well explained. Which part is the start of the color? The stop? What do the different parts mean? Is there a table or colors for reference?