# How can one provide colour to tab completion in tcsh?

Tags: autocomplete, colors, tcsh

([Crossposted to unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/58156/28585))

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12063225/how-to-color-a-prompt-on-freebsd-cshrc) and [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12063749/923794) teach us how to introduce colour into tcsh prompts.

[This webpage](http://www.unix.com/unix-dummies-questions-answers/174664-how-change-color-when-doing-echo-tcsh.html) explains nicely how to get colour into any output of the `echo` command:

```
> echo \\e[1\;30mBLACK\\e[0m
BLACK
> echo '\e[1;30mBLACK\e[0m'
BLACK
```

The word 'BLACK' in the example above is printed with a black (or darkgrey) foreground colour (depending on the overall color scheme).

Now I'd like to introduce this into the `[TAB]` command autocompletion feature of `tcsh`. I tried:

```
complete testcmd 'p/*/`echo '"'"'\e[1;30mf834fef\e[0m'"'"'`/'
```

And I get:

```
> testcmd [TAB]
> testcmd ^[\[1\;30mf834fef^[\[0m
```

Obviously the characters lose their special meaning. Hopefully I just did not get the escaping right. But I tried several other ways. So any help is appreciated.

The real use case is that I've got a command completion that offers three different types of completions and I'd like to visually distinguish the types. Also the alternatives are computed by an external command. That is why I need the completion to use the backticks with an external command, such as `echo`. I don't care about the details of this command. If you make it work in any way with the `tcsh`'s `complete` command I'll probably be able to adapt (thinking `perl -pe` wrappers and such).

The reason why I believe this *has* to work somehow is that the tcsh itself offers coloured command completion if you e.g. type `ls [TAB]`. That works correctly in my setup. Also you can use `ls -1F` inside the autocompletion and the colours that `ls` outputs are also piped through. An example would be:

```
complete testcmd 'p/*/`ls -1F`/'
```

Update: As user mavin points out, the colourization of `ls` in this example is indeed not piped through. The colours of `ls` are lost, but the auto completion can reapply colours according to LS_COLOURS variable based on hints such as the `/` and `*` marker endings as added by the ls. This can be verified by doing

```
complete testcmd 'p/*/`ls --color -1`/'
```

which fails to provide colour, and only provides garbled output. (Literally pipes through the escape character sequences)

I'm on `tcsh` version 6.13.00

Any ideas? Pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, `complete testcmd 'p/*/ls -1F/'`, the colours *aren't* getting passed through from `ls`.  You'll find that you get colour here even if you set `ls` to produce monochrome output, but not if you leave off the `-F`.  What's happening is that tcsh is doing its own colouring based on the symbols added to the end of each filename by `ls -F`.  For example:

```
complete testcmd 'p%*%`echo dir/ symlink@ device# socket=`%'
```

You could exploit this in your completion generator, e.g.,

```
complete testcmd 'p/*/`echo foo bar | perl -lane '"'"'print join " ", map { $_. "%" } @F'"'"'`/'
```

The snag is that you end up with these symbols in your completed command-line, and will have to manually backspace each time.

Comment: This workaround is an excellent example of out-of-the-box thinking. Unfortunately I would not accept the additional backspacing from a usability point of view.

Comment: Confirmed your point that it seems impossible to pass through colours. Based on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4267400/923794) I tried to use [`grc`](http://kassiopeia.juls.savba.sk/~garabik/software/grc.html) inside the backtick completions. The escape codes generated by `grc` also appear literally on the output as sth like `^[[0m^[[33m(^[[0m^[[35m`

Comment: I'm probably going with your answer here despite my earlier comment. I'll also mark this as the answer. Hopefully at one point in time there will be a better way in accomplishing this.

Answer (score 1):

`tcsh` will colour filenames based on their suffix, dependent on the `$LS_COLORS` environment variable (e.g., show all `*.gz` files in red).  You could pre-calculate the list of potential completions, place them all in `$LS_COLORS`, then set up dummy files for the completion to use.  If you use the `precmd` alias, you can have the completions automatically recalculated every time the prompt is shown.

```
complete testcmd "p#*#F:$HOME/.cache/testcmd-completions#"
alias prep-testcmd "setenv LS_COLORS '*red=01;31:*green=01;32:' && rm -r ~/.cache/testcmd-completions && mkdir -p ~/.cache/testcmd-completions && touch ~/.cache/testcmd-completions/red ~/.cache/testcmd-completions/green"
alias precmd prep-testcmd
```

Aside: it'd be nice to use this with a ``-style completion rather than an F-style completion; that way you wouldn't need to create the dummy files.  However, I tried that in tcsh 6.17 and it didn't work.

Comment: Again, a great trick out of your box! I have to think about this. (a) the value of LS_COLORS must be restored - probably with a combination of postcmd/precmd aliases, and (b) if I have a large number of completions the length of LS_COLORS might be a problem.

Comment: Thinking more about it: The sorting of the colourization is time consuming. By doing it in precmd/postcmd it would run for every single command in the shell, even if it is unrelated to `testcmd`. I don't see a way to selectively enable it only for `testcmd` because the shell cannot know what the user is going to type.